# Vimwiki C-Enter or S-Enter does not work in Gnome Terminal

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

I am trying out VimWiki. So far so good, but on Ubuntu 18.04, the Shift-Enter and Ctrl-Enter do not work [1]. Search on the net says Gnome Terminal interprets these key combos as the regular Enter key. So I believe I have to remap these keys to something else or find another terminal program. I have tried Terminator, but it works the same as Gnome Terminal.

[1] https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the key mappings, or you can run Vim as a graphical application (`gvim`).  You may have to install the relevant distribution package (such as `vim-gtk3`), it is sometimes split from the pure terminal application.

I suspect the author of this extension is using Vim as a GUI application because I don't think there are many terminals which preserve these key combinations.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think the creator would use a GUI version, but it makes sense.